# Add content inside html body tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i created a python script with the help of BeautifulSoup and i can get some content from a web site.

Now i want with this script  to place the code inside the body tag  of an html file.

How am i gonna do that ?

thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_old_html)
soup.body.insert(0, your_tag)
print soup
```

More info here:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Adding%20a%20Brand%20New%20Element